# How to get table data from Wikipedia page using python flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I tried scraping a wiki table from IBM  using BeautifulSoup and Pandas. but I am unable to show the result using flask. What could be the reason?

Here is my code:

```py
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    @app.route('/')
    def table():
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM"
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable float-left'}).tbody
        rows=table.find_all('tr')
        columns=[v.text.replace('\n', '')for v in rows [0].find_all('th')]
        return(columns)
        df= pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    for i in range(1, len(rows)):
        tds=rows[i].find_all('td')
        if len(tds)==6:
            values=[tds[0].text.replace('\n',''),tds[1].text.replace('\n',''),tds[2].text.replace('\n',''), tds[3].text.replace('\n',''),tds[4].text.replace('\n',''),tds[5].text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\n', ' ')]
        df=df.append(pd.Series(values,index=columns),ignore_index=True)
         return(df)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your python file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

@app.route('/')
def table():
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable float-left'}).tbody
    rows=table.find_all('tr')
    columns=[v.text.replace('\n', '')for v in rows [0].find_all('th')]
    # return(columns)
    df= pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    for i in range(1, len(rows)):
        tds=rows[i].find_all('td')
        if len(tds)==6:
            values=[tds[0].text.replace('\n',''),tds[1].text.replace('\n',''),tds[2].text.replace('\n',''), tds[3].text.replace('\n',''),tds[4].text.replace('\n',''),tds[5].text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\n', ' ')]
            df=df.append(pd.Series(values,index=columns),ignore_index=True)
    return render_template('index.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here is your html file which should be located in your project/templates path:

```
{% for table in tables %}
            {{titles[loop.index]}}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: work it brother. thanks brother

Answer (score -1):

convert the data frame to html using pandas.to_html and return that.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    @app.route('/')
    def table():
        data=[]
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM"
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable float-left'})
        rows=table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            data.append([cell.text.replace('\n', '')for cell in row.find_all(['th', 'td'])])

        df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns=data[0])

        return df.to_html(header="true", table_id="table")


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```